# Shutdown the celery worker

Tags: python, celery

for example:

```
@app.task()
def f(num):
    if num == 0:
        # shutdown this worker
        # celery will not distribute any tasks to this worker
    else:
        return num
```

celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -n worker1

When celery distributes 0 to worker1, worker1 will be killed. 
In the doc, [The broadcast() function](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v2.2.5/userguide/workers.html#the-broadcast-function)

```
>>> broadcast("shutdown") # shutdown all workers
>>> broadcast("shutdown, destination="worker1.example.com")
```

but it is wrong, I change it to

```
>>> broadcast("shutdown", destination=["worker1"])
```

it also doesn't work.

So, how to achieve this function?

Comment: Well it looks like in your broadcast and in the celery docs it is missing a quote

Comment: @user2097159 Yeah, but it also didn't work when I added the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Normally worker name starts with '*celery@*'. So in your case try below code:
`celery.control.broadcast('shutdown', destination=['celery@worker1'])`